# Limit of integral from t/2 to t

Tags: calculus, limits, improper-integrals

So I've been trying to understand some calculus, and I found this. Supposedly if $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)<\infty$ and $f(x)\geq0$ then we have $$\lim_{t \to \infty}\int_{\frac{t}{2}}^{t} f(x)\,dx=0$$ Is that true? And if so, why is that true?

Comment: Did you mean $f(x) \geq 0$?

Comment: If $f(x)\le 0$, then it can be $ \int_0^\infty f(x)=-\infty$ and the statement is false

Comment: Sorry, fixed it

Comment: additional constraint of non-negative $f$ is not needed.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
$$\int_{0}^{t} f(x)\,dx=\int_0^{\frac{t}{2}} f(x)\,dx+\int_{\frac{t}{2}}^{t} f(x)\,dx$$

Answer (score 1):

This is true if we assume the that the integral of f converge

Hint :

Cauchy criterion